# Show names and ids from VoteTypes, PostTypes, etc. tables in the Data Explorer UI

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, user-interface, data-explorer

While writing a query in the Data Explorer, I nearly always have to interrupt the process to query the `VoteTypes`, `PostTypes`, and / or `PostHistoryTypes` tables (so I can remember the Ids I need).  I think it would be convenient to have access to the values in those tables directly from the UI (without having to do `SELECT * FROM VoteTypes`).

Could we have something like that?

I realize I could save the values from those tables somewhere on my computer, but they'd (possibly) get out-of-date periodically, and if new "`____Types`" tables are added, I'd have to manually update my local list.

---

I'm not a UI person, but here's a *possible* implementation: next to each of these "`____Types`" tables, add a link you can click  that pops up a list of the values from that table (incredibly awesome* mock-up below):

[image: These are not the Post History Types you're looking for]

I'm not married to this specific implementation, anything reasonable would do.  This feature-request just seemed too lazy without some kind of suggested solution =)

<sub>*Awesomeness may vary. We offer no actual guarantee (implied or explicit) of awesomeness regarding the mock-up.</sub>

Comment: I use [this](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/36599/show-all-types) in another tab and would prefer to have the data in the UI too.

Comment: @Gilles That query was a great idea!  I wish I would have thought of that months ago.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, you can, actually.

I've already got a [prototype implementation](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/message/909747#909747) of this that I'll be tightening up this weekend and passing along to waffles for review.

**Update**: This is done now (provided there's no major issues with my implementation). I'll be pushing it out to my repository later tonight after make a few other changes.

Some screenshots of what it looks like:

[image: icon to indicate there's a helper view]

...which you click to open the helper view as an overlay to the side bar:

[image: open helper view]

Comment: Great minds think alike!  I look forward to see this =)

Comment: I had something come up this weekend, so unfortunately still not quite there. :/ Working on it though...

Comment: Yes, I see that [something came up](http://chat.meta.stackoverflow.com/transcript/89?m=913132#913132) ;-)

Comment: This was a less enjoyable something. :P

Comment: The magical green checkmark is yours!

Comment: @TimStone Have you already added it to the repository?

Comment: @Idolon I did a while back, yeah. It isn't deployed to the live site yet, though.